How do I call a method in a second class using the same declared object?
I have a class A method that is getting called in a class B method (this part works just fine). I want to call another class A method in a class C method, but using the same declared object.
The method I am trying to call returns a status of a system, so it has to be part of the same declared object. I know I need to write an accessor function for this in class B, but I'm not exactly sure what that would look like.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
class MyClassA{
    public:
    void myMethodInit(){
        //stuff
    }
    void myMethodStatus(){
        //stuff
    }

};

class MyClassB{
    public:
    MyClassA objectA;
    
    void myMethod3(){
        objectA.myMethodInit(); //This call is working fine
    }
    
    //Need an accessor function to let another class use objectA
    
};

class MyClassC{
    public:
    
    void myMethod4(){
        objectA.myMethodStatus(); //Need to call the same object as in MyClassB
    }
    
};

I could not figure out how to correctly google my issue so here I am. I have simplified my issue down as much as I could.

myMethod4 needs to be passed a reference (const if possible) to objectA OR an instance of MyClassB once the considered accessor has been added. BUT!!! What if MyClassB picks up another function, a sort-of visitor pattern, that receives a reference to class that contains a function that receives a reference to objectA? Make MyClassC visit MyClassB? That way objectA doesn't need to be exposed.

I like how you've minimized this example, but you may have stripped out too much of the context around how these classes need to interact.

"but using the same declared object" -- Which object is that? Each MyClassB object uses its objectA field to invoke a MyClassA method. When a MyClassC object wants to use the "same" object, which MyClassB object contains the desired MyClassA instance?

"I could not figure out how to correctly google my issue" -- I tried searching this site for [c++] invoke method other class without much luck, but when I changed that to [c++] call method other class, I found Call a method from A class in constructor of other class. While this is not a good example of how to write a question, you might find the answers informative.

If you want to share ownership of the same object between multiple other objects (including managing of the shared object's lifecycle) you can do that with help of std::shared_ptr:
#include <memory>

struct A {
    void Foo() 
    void Bar()
};

struct B {
    std::shared_ptr<A> m_aPtr;

    void Foo() {
        m_aPtr->Foo();
    }
};

struct C {
    std::shared_ptr<A> m_aPtr;

    void Bar() {
        m_aPtr->Bar();
    }
};

int main() {
    const auto aPtr = std::make_shared<A>();
    B b{aPtr};
    C c{aPtr};

    return 0;
}

Here both b and c refer to the same object managed by shared pointers and can access its member functions as needed.

Since you are not very clear on the constraints of the implementation, in addition to Aleksandr's answer, your problem can be solved in the following way as well. However, please note that my answer doesn't provide any specific advantages over Aleksandr's answer. My aim is to provide just a different method.
To allow MyClassC to use the same instance of MyClassA as is used in MyClassB, you need to provide a way for MyClassC to access objectA from MyClassB. You can achieve this by writing an accessor method in MyClassB that returns a reference (or pointer) to objectA.
class MyClassA
{
public:
    void myMethodInit()
    {
        // Initialize stuff
    }
    void myMethodStatus()
    {
        // Check and return status
    }
};

class MyClassB
{
public:
    MyClassA objectA;

    void myMethod3()
    {
        objectA.myMethodInit(); // This call is working fine
    }

    // Accessor method to provide access to objectA
    MyClassA& getObjectA()
    {
        return objectA;
    }
};

class MyClassC
{
public:
    void myMethod4(MyClassB& objB)
    {
        // Use the accessor to get the reference to objectA
        MyClassA& objectA = objB.getObjectA();
        objectA.myMethodStatus(); // Call method on the same instance of objectA
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClassB objB;
    objB.myMethod3(); // Initialize objectA

    MyClassC objC;
    objC.myMethod4(objB); // Call method on the same objectA instance

    return 0;
}

Again, as a comment pointed out, you may have stripped too much information trying to simplify the example. Therefore, the answer you may be seeking might be far from what I have provided. If you update your question, drop me a comment and I can update my answer accordingly.
